# Cannot group fields in Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Software: MS Excel 2016

Excel File: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Group)

---

I am unable to group fields in pivot table of [Excel file](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Group).

Graffiti table is linked with Calendar table via Date (in PowerPivot > Data Model), so why is there difficulty in grouping the following.

However if I unlink the tables (which is what I DO NOT want to do), then it works

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can add Pivot Table into a Data Model, only raw data can.  What you can do is copy data `A1:B23`, and `Paste Special > Paste Link` to `Sheet2` (or any sheet you prefer).  Then add `Sheet2` as a new Data Model.

Comment: @ian0411 Ok let me try...

Comment: @ian0411 It's still unlinked with Calendar. I copied and pasted link, then added to data model. New table in data model is not linked to Calendar.

Comment: So when you pasted in new sheet, did you see the formula inside every cell like `=Sheet1!B2` etc?

Comment: It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgIbV.png

Comment: @ian0411 Yes I did (by the way, uploaded updated file to GitHub)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156376/discussion-between-ian0411-and-rhonda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his online course, *Building BI with Pivot Tables*, Ken Puls, Microsoft Excel MVP explains that if you build your pivot table from the data model, grouping won't work. He also explains that the only exception to this is that for Excel 2016 they fixed the ability to group dates. He says other grouping still doesn't work in Excel 2016. If you make your Pivot Table from your "Table1" in your "DSNY_Graffiti_Information" tab in your Workbook instead of from the Power Pivot data model, you can group:

[image]

For the Pivot Table above, I just clicked in "Table1" in your "DSNY_Graffiti_Information" tab, then used Insert -> Pivot Table, and I used your "RESOLUTION_ACTION" column for both the "Rows" and "Values". It defaulted the values to count (i.e., "Count of RESOLUTION_ACTION").

[image]

Then I selected all of the "10-..." entries in the Pivot Table, right-clicked, and clicked "Group".

I hope this helps some.